# Error: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to move multiple selected item from one ListBox to another ListBox using this code

```
protected void imgbtnMoveRightListBox_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in lstboxSkill.SelectedItem)
    {
        lstBBoxSkill2.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

but it shows an error

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' because
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' does not contain a public
>   definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I don't know why this error occured.

Please help me to fix it

Comment: `lstboxSkill.SelectedItem` is not a "list", it's just that one item in the list that was clicked which triggered the event. Thus, the foreach wouldn't make sense.

Comment: your code sounds like for each item in the item, which is logically wrong..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Snap shot of the page where I am using this]

Please check this snap shot I have created and its working fine.
and the code behind code is given below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstboxSkill.Items.Add("ASP.Net");
        lstboxSkill.Items.Add("C#");
        lstboxSkill.Items.Add("AJAX");
        lstboxSkill.Items.Add("JavaScript");
        lstboxSkill.Items.Add("HTML");
        lstboxSkill.Items.Add("HTML5");
        lstboxSkill.Items.Add("JQuery");
    }
protected void imgbtnMoveRightListBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem Item in lstboxSkill.Items)
        {
            if (Item.Selected == true)
            {
                lstBBoxSkill2.Items.Add(Item);
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: your code is perfectly well even i have tried it in a seperate application and it is working well there,but don't know why in my application it is not working.. in my application i am dynamically binding first list-box from a dropdown selected value and then according to firstlist box item i am filling second listbox

Comment: can you please send me the code you have written for bind the 1st list box and then the second one with screen shot @akvickyit7

Answer (score 1):

Check this code.

```
protected void imgbtnMoveRightListBox_Click(object senderImageClickEventArge)

    {
    foreach (ListItem item in lstboxSkill.Items)
    {
        lstBBoxSkill2.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`lstboxSkill.SelectedItem` is a [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is neither an array nor an object collection that implements the [System.Collections.IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) or [System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) interface, so it's not possible to do `foreach` against it.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
foreach (var item in lstboxSkill.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        lstBBoxSkill2.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to verify the item is selected before adding it, don't you?

Comment: That would add ALL the items in the list. I think the intention is to add only the selected items.

Comment: I have changed the answer, thanks for the input guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the SelectedItem property returns only the item with the lowest index out of the list of items selected. You should change your code as

```
protected void imgbtnMoveRightListBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem Item in lstboxSkill.Items)
        {
            if (Item.Selected == true)
            {
                lstBBoxSkill2.Items.Add(Item);
            }
        }            
    }
```

And set both listbox SelectionMode="Multiple".

Hope this will help you. Don't forget marked as answer

Thanks
Solomon S.

Comment: yes SOLOMON SARKAR code is working but the problem is in lstboxSkill always first item is selected true and not the other items. It is not getting which items are selected except first .

Comment: No No I've checked it and its working even if you select any index instead of first one. @akvickyit7

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void imgbtnMoveRightListBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbltxt.Visible = false;
    if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0) // in this we are checking whether a single item is clicked.
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)  // we are looping through the list box items
        {
            if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected) // finding the selected items
            {
                if (!arraylist1.Contains(ListBox1.Items[i]))
                {
                    arraylist1.Add(ListBox1.Items[i]); //if found then adding those items to the array list
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!ListBox2.Items.Contains(((ListItem)arraylist1[i])))
            {
                ListBox2.Items.Add(((ListItem)arraylist1[i])); // we are adding the array elements to the second list box 
            }
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(((ListItem)arraylist1[i]));
        }
        ListBox2.SelectedIndex = -1; 
    }
    else
    {
        lbltxt.Visible = true;
        lbltxt.Text = "Please select atleast one in Listbox1 to move";
    }
}
```

**[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/570319/ASP-NET-Move-Items-from-One-Listbox-to-Another-Lis)**